# Javascript - How do you find the total increase of a number over time?

Tags: javascript, math

Thanks for stopping by!

I am creating a small program that will display the total compound interest.
For example, let's say every month a person were to get 5% increase on their monthly income.  They start off with $1,000, but after a year, they would be making $1,820 per month.

I got it to the point where it will display the monthly income after the 1 year ($1,820), but I can't seem to find a way to get it to display the total increase you made over the 1 year.

Month 1 =   +50
Month 2 =   +104
Month 3 =   +160
Month 4 =   +220
Month 5 =   +282
Month 6 =   +348
Month 7 =   +417
Month 8 =   +490
Month 9 =   +566
Month 10 =  +647
Month 11 =  +731
Month 12 =  +820
________________
Total =    $4,835

Normally this would be very easy to do, but since the amount, percentage, and duration are all variables, I am at a loss.

Basically what I am looking to do would be

"Amount: 1000
 Percentage: 5
 Duration: 12
 Total: $1,820
 Total Money Gained: $4,835"

Thank you so much for taking the time to help!
Have a fantastic rest of your day!

**HTML**

```
<input id="amount" type="number" onchange="myFunction()">
<input id="percentage" type="number" onchange="myFunction()">
<input id="duration" type="number" onchange="myFunction()">
<h2 id="payment"></h2>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function myFunction() {
    var amount = document.getElementById('amount').value;
    var percentage = document.getElementById('percentage').value;
    var duration = document.getElementById('duration').value;

    var payment = Math.round(amount * (1 + (percentage * 0.01) / duration)**(duration**2));

    document.getElementById('payment').textContent=payment;
}
```

[**CodePen Example**](https://codepen.io/ScooterMcGee/pen/zLwNVW?editors=1010)

Comment: I think your math (and expected value) is off. Why raise `duration` to the power of 2? Check http://www.moneychimp.com/calculator/compound_interest_calculator.htm , result should be `1,795.86`

Comment: Oh my gosh!  Thank you so much for that!  I didn't even notice that my math was off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use looping to determine the increase every month. After getting the increase, add it to the total number of increase.

```js
function increase() {
  var amount = document.getElementById('amount').value;
  var percentage = document.getElementById('percentage').value;
  var duration = document.getElementById('duration').value;

  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 1; i <= duration; i++) {
    var payment = Math.round(amount * (1 + (percentage * 0.01) / i) ** (i ** 2));
    total += (payment - amount);
  }
  document.getElementById('payment').textContent = payment;
  console.log(total);
}
```

```html
<p>Amount <input id="amount" type="number" value="0" onchange="increase()"></p>
<p>Percentage <input id="percentage" value="5" type="number" onchange="increase()"></p>
<p>Duration <input id="duration" type="number" value="12" onchange="increase()"></p>
<div id="payment"></div>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly!  Thank you for the help on this one.

Answer (score 2):

You need to loop through each tick in `duration`, calculate the difference from the base amount, and print it:

```js
const outputElm = document.getElementById("payment");
const appendP = textContent => {
  outputElm.appendChild(document.createElement('p'))
    .textContent = textContent;
};
function somethingHere() {
  outputElm.textContent="";
  var base = document.getElementById('amount').value;
  var percentage = document.getElementById('percentage').value;
  var duration = document.getElementById('duration').value;
  
  const multiplier = 1 + (percentage*0.01);
  let payment = base;
  for (let i = 0; i < duration; i++) {
    payment *= multiplier;
    appendP(`Month ${i + 1}: +$${Math.round(payment - base)}`);
  }
  appendP('----------------');
  appendP(`Total: $${Math.round(payment)}`);
}
```

```html
<p>Amount <input id="amount" type="number" value="0" onchange="somethingHere()"></p>

<p>Percentage <input id="percentage" value="5" type="number" onchange="somethingHere()"></p>

<p>Duration <input id="duration" type="number" value="12" onchange="somethingHere()"></p>

<div id="payment"></div>
```

Comment: i check the result. it is not the same as the OP describes.

Comment: OP's math (and expected value) is off, see comment on question

Answer (score 2):

To begin with, your compound interest calculation is wrong. Using the variables `a` (amount), `i` (increase) and `d` (duration), the compounded amount would be expressed as:

[image: compounded amount]

Then, for the total amount gained over the duration, the sum expression would be:

[image: sum expression]

Which can be rewritten as:

[image: sum rewritten]

Plugging that into the JavaScript code, you get the following:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var a = +document.getElementById('amount').value;
  var i = +document.getElementById('percentage').value / 100;
  var d = +document.getElementById('duration').value;

  var payment = a * ((1 + i) ** d);
  var total = a / i * (((1 + i) ** d) + i * ((1 + i) ** d - d - 1) - 1); 

  document.getElementById('payment').textContent = payment;
  document.getElementById('total').textContent = total;
}
```

```html
<input id="amount" type="number" onchange="myFunction()">
<input id="percentage" type="number" onchange="myFunction()">
<input id="duration" type="number" onchange="myFunction()">
<h2 id="payment"></h2>
<h2 id="total"></h2>
```