# Javascript - How do you find the total balance compound interest over time?

Tags: javascript, calculation

I am trying to create a small program that will display the total compound interest.
For example, let's say every year a person were to get 5% increase on their maintenance fees. They start off at $100, but after a year, they would be paying  $105 per year and after 50 years they would be paying $1147.

I have found a formula on this site ([Javascript - How do you find the total increase of a number over time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51489666/javascript-how-do-you-find-the-total-increase-of-a-number-over-time)). This works for the payment amounts each year, however the total amount paid appears to be incorrect.

This is the code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var a = +document.getElementById('amount').value;
  var i = +document.getElementById('percentage').value / 100;
  var d = +document.getElementById('duration').value;

  var payment = a * ((1 + i) ** d);
  var total = a / i * (((1 + i) ** d) + i * ((1 + i) ** d - d - 1) - 1);

  document.getElementById('payment').textContent = payment;
  document.getElementById('total').textContent = total;
}
```

```html
<input id="amount" type="number" onchange="myFunction()">
<input id="percentage" type="number" onchange="myFunction()">
<input id="duration" type="number" onchange="myFunction()">
<h2 id="payment"></h2>
<h2 id="total"></h2>
```

I need to calculate the total amount paid after 50 years.
According to this formula (Using the example amount:100, percentage:5, duration:50) the total value is $16981.54. However after manually adding all the yearly values (see below) it should work out at $21,985. What is going wrong?

This is the breakdown:

```
Year 1 Value:105
Year 2 Value:110
Year 3 Value:116
Year 4 Value:122
Year 5 Value:128
Year 6 Value:134
Year 7 Value:141
Year 8 Value:148
Year 9 Value:155
Year 10 Value:163
Year 11 Value:171
Year 12 Value:180
Year 13 Value:189
Year 14 Value:198
Year 15 Value:208
Year 16 Value:218
Year 17 Value:229
Year 18 Value:241
Year 19 Value:253
Year 20 Value:265
Year 21 Value:279
Year 22 Value:293
Year 23 Value:307
Year 24 Value:323
Year 25 Value:339
Year 26 Value:356
Year 27 Value:373
Year 28 Value:392
Year 29 Value:412
Year 30 Value:432
Year 31 Value:454
Year 32 Value:476
Year 33 Value:500
Year 34 Value:525
Year 35 Value:552
Year 36 Value:579
Year 37 Value:608
Year 38 Value:639
Year 39 Value:670
Year 40 Value:704
Year 41 Value:739
Year 42 Value:776
Year 43 Value:815
Year 44 Value:856
Year 45 Value:899
Year 46 Value:943
Year 47 Value:991
Year 48 Value:1040
Year 49 Value:1092
Year 50 Value:1147
```

Comment: You should parse your input as integer. Input values are numbers represented as strings

Comment: @LelioFaieta - They are, note the `+` on the lines getting the values. That converts string to number.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks I didn’t notice that. Was looking for parseInt! :-)

Comment: So the answer you took it from is incorrect. There are other answers in the link you posted - each gives different result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct formula is T = a/i*((1+i)^(n+1) - (1+i)) with n the number of years, a your money and i the interest rate.

Comment: Why is this voted down if the calculation is correct

Comment: I don't know, the formula written by the author is wrong.